Detecting Click and DoubleClick using Observables
I have a stream of click events and I want to determine from that stream whether a single click or a double clicked was performed by the user. Currently I'm attempting to do this by buffering the values over a specified doubleClickTime (e.g. 300ms) and taking the count of those values.
So starting with this
IObservable<Click> clicks = ...

I'm attempting to use the buffer operator with an opening selector and closing selector
IDisposable subscription = clicks.Buffer(clicks, _ => Observable.Timer(doubleClickTime))
.Subscribe(items =>
 {
    if(items.Count > 1)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Double Click");
    }
    else
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Single Click");
    }
 });

However, the issue with the above is that I get the following output when double clicking
Double Click
Single Click

i.e., it registers a double click and a single click. I think this is because my opening selector is also the click event, so on the double click a new buffer window is started.
How do I compose the opening selector correctly such that it only fires when no buffering is taking place?
Is there a better way to do this?
Update
Presumably it is similar to this example written in rxjs, but can't quite figure out how to translate the below in C#
const clickOrDoubleClick$ = click$.pipe(
buffer(click$.pipe(switchMap(() => timer(DOUBLE_CLICK_INTERVAL)))),
map((clicksArr) =>
clicksArr.length > 1 ? createDoubleClick() : createClick() ));


Where are these clicks coming from? If they're coming from a web-browser or desktop OS then you don't need to do this because both of those platforms will do double-click identification for you - so you just need to change your upstream data-source to listen for click and doubleclick events and processs them as-you-wish.

Also, the double-click timeout period is a per-machine setting - just because one person clicked twice in (say) 200ms doesn't mean it was actually a double-click for them - or anyone else.

It's coming from a desktop app and I'm aware of click event that are there, but this is part of a larger 'gesture detector' that also detects hold events, drag events, (possibly triple click) etc.
Yes, I plan to get that time from the system later. For now just hard coded.

I think you've encountered a deceptively difficult problem.

"but this is part of a larger 'gesture detector' that also detects hold events, drag events, (possibly triple click) etc." - again, the OS does this for you - there's no need to reinvent the wheel. (I linked to the docs for pen/touch gestures, but the system supports mouse-gestures too, IIRC)

Good to know, albeit the mouse actions look a little limited at first glance. Either way think the above holds as an observables question in its own right.

You can use the Delay() operator to create a new observable, where every item is delayed by a fixed time from the original observable. When you combine the original observable and the "delayed" observable with CombineLatest(), you will either see a change in the original observable or in the "delayed" observable. The following marble diagram illustrate the situation:
orig : ---1----2--3-----4------5--6----7----8----
delay: -----1----2--3-----4------5--6----7----8--
comb :      ^--^-^^-^---^-^----^-^^-^--^-^--^-^--

The ^ indicate where the CombineLatest() observable would emit a new value.
To see/recognize an actual "change" you have to consume the values from the CombineLatest() observable and save in a "state" what the previous values were. This way you will see if the "original" value was changed or the "delayed" value was changed. Based on these information, you will be able to decide if it was a fast double click (the "original" value was changed) or a slow single click (the "delayed" value was changed). I came up with the following solution:
First we build an observable where the values have a index counter so we can recognize that it is definitely a new value. This is needed because a value could be equal to a previous value when emitted (based on the Equals() implementation) and we wouldn't see a change. Creating a container with an index counter would be similar to what Timestamp() or TimeInterval() are doing. I build my own container class and observable:
public class IndexedValue
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Index {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"V={Value}, Index={Index}";
    }
}

ISubject<string> clicksSource = new Subject<string>();

IObservable<IndexedValue> indexedClicksSource = clicksSource.Select((v, i) => {
        return new IndexedValue
        {
            Value = v,
            Index = i
        };
    });

(I use the string type for the emitted values during developing/testing, but it could be a generic solution with T or your specific type Click. Also, in retrospect, I could have used Timestamp() and it would works most likely the same)
Now we build the CombineLatest() observable:
indexedClicksSource.CombineLatest(
        indexedClicksSource.Delay(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(doubleClickRangeInMs))
            .StartWith(default(IndexedValue)),
        (original, delayed) => {
            return new 
            {
                Original = original,
                Delayed = delayed
            };
        })

The Delay() observable will start with a NULL value so the CombineLatest() call will fire immediately even when the "delayed" observable hasn't generated a value yet. This is important in case the original observable starts immediately with two short clicks for a double click. The marble diagram might look now like this:
orig : ---1----2--3---...
delay: ---N-1----2--3-...
comb :    ^-^--^-^^-^-...

We use the Scan() operator to work with a "state" where we hold the information about the previous CombineLatest() combination as well as any information about an active single/double click check. The state class is defined as follow:
public class DelayedStateInfo
{
    public IndexedValue PreviousOriginalValue {get; set;}
    public IndexedValue PreviousDelayedValue {get; set;}
    public IndexedValue StartValue {get; set;}
    public IndexedValue EndValue {get; set;}
}

The PreviousOriginalValue and PreviousDelayedValue properties are the two values from the CombineLatest() call. The StartValue and EndValue properties are used to decide if we a building/seeing a double click or a single click. The StartValue will be the first click, the EndValue will be the second click. Depending on the values they hold (more precisely the Index values they hold) we will identify if it is a double click or a single click. The Scan() call can look like this:
.Scan(default(DelayedStateInfo), (oldState, current) => {
            DelayedStateInfo newState = new()
            {
                PreviousOriginalValue = current.Original,
                PreviousDelayedValue = current.Delayed
            };
            if (oldState == default)
            {
                // the actual seed
                newState.StartValue = current.Original;
                return newState;
            }
            bool originalUpdated = oldState.PreviousOriginalValue.Index != current.Original.Index;
            if (originalUpdated)
            {
                // the original value is updated, must be a double click or a new sequence
                if (oldState.EndValue == null)
                {
                    // it's a double click
                    newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                    newState.EndValue = current.Original;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // there already was a click, so start a new sequence
                    newState.StartValue = current.Original;
                }
                return newState;
            }
            else
            {
                // the delayed value is updated, must be a single click or a catch up
                if (oldState.EndValue == null && oldState.StartValue.Index <= current.Delayed.Index)
                {
                    // single click
                    newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                    newState.EndValue = current.Delayed;
                    return newState;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // a catch up, but there was already a single or double click sent, so do nothing
                    newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                    newState.EndValue = oldState.EndValue;
                    return newState;
                }
            }
        })

This will generate DelayedStateInfo instances as the original (and "delayed") values are emitted and we will use a Select() operator to build the meta information if there was a single or double click. I use the following class to hold this information:
public class DoubleClickInfo {
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public bool IsDoubleClick {get; set;}

    public override string ToString() {
        return $"V={Value}, doubleClick={IsDoubleClick}";
    }
}

The Select() call can look like this:
        .DistinctUntilChanged(it =>
        {
            int startIndex = it.StartValue.Index;
            int? endIndex = it.EndValue?.Index;
            return $"{startIndex}|{endIndex}";
        })
        .Select(info => {
            if (info.EndValue == null)
            {
                return null; // no click yet
            }
            if (info.StartValue.Index == info.EndValue.Index)
            {
                // a single click
                return new DoubleClickInfo {
                    Value = info.EndValue.Value,
                    IsDoubleClick = false
                };
            }
            // a double click
            return new DoubleClickInfo {
                Value = info.EndValue.Value,
                IsDoubleClick = true
            };
        })
        .Where(it => it != null)

The DistinctUntilChanged() call is used to filter out states which actually doesn't show a change. The Where() call at the end is used in case we couldn't identify a click yet (EndValue is null).
With all these code snippets we can build the following example program:
sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ISubject<string> clicksSource = new Subject<string>();

IObservable<IndexedValue> indexedClicksSource = clicksSource.Select((v, i) => {
    return new IndexedValue
    {
        Value = v,
        Index = i
    };
});

IObservable<DoubleClickInfo> aggregatedSource = indexedClicksSource.CombineLatest(
    indexedClicksSource.Delay(
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(doubleClickRangeInMs))
        .StartWith(default(IndexedValue)),
    (original, delayed) => {
        return new 
        {
            Original = original,
            Delayed = delayed
        };
    })
    .Scan(default(DelayedStateInfo), (oldState, current) => {
        DelayedStateInfo newState = new()
        {
            PreviousOriginalValue = current.Original,
            PreviousDelayedValue = current.Delayed
        };
        if (oldState == default)
        {
            DebugScanDelegate("Start seed");
            // the actual seed
            newState.StartValue = current.Original;
            return newState;
        }
        bool originalUpdated = oldState.PreviousOriginalValue.Index != current.Original.Index;
        if (originalUpdated)
        {
            // the original value is updated, must be a double click or a new sequence
            if (oldState.EndValue == null)
            {
                // it's a double click
                newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                newState.EndValue = current.Original;
            }
            else 
            {
                // there already was a click, so start a new sequence
                newState.StartValue = current.Original;
            }
            return newState;
        }
        else
        {
            // the delayed value is updated, must be a single click or a catch up
            if (oldState.EndValue == null && oldState.StartValue.Index <= current.Delayed.Index)
            {
                // single click
                newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                newState.EndValue = current.Delayed;
                return newState;
            }
            else 
            {
                // a catch up, but there was already a single or double click sent, so do nothing
                newState.StartValue = oldState.StartValue;
                newState.EndValue = oldState.EndValue;
                return newState;
            }
        }
    })
    .DistinctUntilChanged(it =>
    {
        int startIndex = it.StartValue.Index;
        int? endIndex = it.EndValue?.Index;
        return $"{startIndex}|{endIndex}";
    })
    .Select(info => {
        if (info.EndValue == null)
        {
            return null; // no click yet
        }
        if (info.StartValue.Index == info.EndValue.Index)
        {
            // a single click
            return new DoubleClickInfo {
                Value = info.EndValue.Value,
                IsDoubleClick = false
            };
        }
        // a double click
        return new DoubleClickInfo {
            Value = info.EndValue.Value,
            IsDoubleClick = true
        };
    })
    .Where(it => it != null);

aggregatedSource.Subscribe(it => {
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds:00000}ms| Subscribe called with: {it}");
});

EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_11");
SleepWithOutput(500);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_12");
SleepWithOutput(150);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_13");
SleepWithOutput(450);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_14");
SleepWithOutput(400);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_15");
SleepWithOutput(350);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_16");
SleepWithOutput(300);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_17");
SleepWithOutput(250);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_18");
SleepWithOutput(200);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_19");
SleepWithOutput(500);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_20");
SleepWithOutput(100);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_21");
SleepWithOutput(350);

This will generate the following debug output:
00057ms| Emit value str_11
00076ms| Sleep for 500ms
00386ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_11, doubleClick=False
00576ms| Emit value str_12
00576ms| Sleep for 150ms
00726ms| Emit value str_13
00726ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_13, doubleClick=True
00726ms| Sleep for 450ms
01177ms| Emit value str_14
01177ms| Sleep for 400ms
01476ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_14, doubleClick=False
01577ms| Emit value str_15
01577ms| Sleep for 350ms
01876ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_15, doubleClick=False
01927ms| Emit value str_16
01927ms| Sleep for 300ms
02227ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_16, doubleClick=False
02227ms| Emit value str_17
02227ms| Sleep for 250ms
02477ms| Emit value str_18
02477ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_18, doubleClick=True
02477ms| Sleep for 200ms
02677ms| Emit value str_19
02677ms| Sleep for 500ms
02976ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_19, doubleClick=False
03177ms| Emit value str_20
03177ms| Sleep for 100ms
03277ms| Emit value str_21
03278ms| Subscribe called with: V=str_21, doubleClick=True
03278ms| Sleep for 350ms

This shows you how it recognized single and double clicks based on the time when the original events/values were emitted.

An different solution (and easier I guess) would be to use Timeout() and Switch() to build an observable, which have timeout markers in them. When the time distance between two clicks is too big, then we insert a "timeout marker" to indicate that the timeout was reached and we have only a single-click. Then we always check the next two emitted values from the observable. When it is a "click" and a "timeout marker", then it was a single-click. When it is a "click" and another "click", then it was a double-click.
The observable returned by Timeout() will either fail with an exception on the OnError() handler or with a continuation observable, depending which overload of the method is used. We don't want the observable to die, so we use the Timeout() overload, which falls back to a different observable when a timeout occured. This fallback observable only produce our "timeout marker".
We first use Select() to build an observable which re-emitted the original value, but also have a timeout component which adds the "timeout marker". In this example, I will use null as the "timeout marker". We would like to generate an observable like this:
orig : ---1--N2--3--N--4--N---5--6--N-7--N-8--N-

The N indicate the "timeout marker" after two - periods. The time between 2 and 3 was too short, so it was a double-click. The same for 5 and 6. In all the other cases, the timeout occurred first, so it was a single-click. When we check every two emitted values, we can decide if it was a single-click or double-click:
orig : ---1--N2--3--N--4--N---5--6--N-7--N-8--N-
          [ss][dd]  *  [ss]   [dd]  * [ss] [ss]

The positions marked with * are remnants from a timeout, where the previous click was already identified as a double-click. We have to check for them, too (and ignore them).
When we use Select() to build an observable with "timeout markers", we don't get one continues observable. Instead we get an observable of observables, like IObservable<IObservable<string>>. The marble diagram might look like this:
orig : ---1---2--3-----4------5--6----7----8----
           \   \  \     \      \  \    \    \
            \   \  \     \      \  \    \    \
             N   N  N     N      N  N    N    N

We will use Switch() to "concat" these observables. However, it isn't a real concatenation (there is even a Concat() operator for what). Instead the Switch() operator will replace the current observable with the new one, like a "hot swap", without any subscriptions noticing the swap. We use it here to switch to the "new" click when it occurred before the "timeout marker" was produced. This will be later our double-click.
Such an observable can be build like this:
ISubject<string> clicksSource = new Subject<string>();

IObservable<string> clicksWithTimeouts = clicksSource.Select(it => {
    return Observable.Never<string>()
        .StartWith(it)
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(doubleClickRangeInMs),
                     Observable.Never<string>().StartWith((string)null));
    })
    .Switch();

(I use string types for the click object during developing/testing, but it could be your Click class as well)
The inner part of the Select() method will build for each original emitted value a new observable with the only values it (the original value) and the timeout marker null. The Switch() operator will "hot swap" the active observable.
Now with an observable with original values and "timeout markers", we will use Scan() to iterate over the observable values and check/remember, if we see a null for a single-click or a string for a double-click. We use the following class for the state for Scan():
public class Pair
{
    public bool HasSecond {get; set;}
    public bool WasDoubleClick {get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"HasSecond={HasSecond}, WasDoubleClick={WasDoubleClick}";
    }
}

There are three cases when the next Scan() handler is called:

The state is null: This is the start state, but also the state when we received a "timeout marker" after a double-click. We will use it to set the state, that we received the next click, but don't know yet if it will be a single-click or double-click.
The state is an object, but HasSecond is false: We have previously detected the first click of a potential double-click, but we don't know what it will be. But when we look at the current value, we know if it is a single-click or double-click, based on if it is the "timeout marker" (null) or not.
The state is an object and HasSecond is true: We have already identified a double-click (or single-click) previously and we start with a new check.

The Scan() call can look like this:
IObservable<Pair> pairObservable = clicksWithTimeouts.Scan(default(Pair), (accu, next) => {
    if (accu == null || accu.HasSecond)
    {
        // start new sequence
        if (next != null)
        {
            return new Pair(); // HasSecond is false
        }
        else
        {
            // was a NULL after a double click, so do nothing
            return null;
        }
    }
    // we received the first half, but now know what it will be
    // depending on the value of "next"
    return new Pair
    {
        HasSecond = true,
        WasDoubleClick = next != null
    };
})
.Where(it => it != null)
.Where(it => it.HasSecond);

The Where() operators will give us only Pair instances we are interested in (completed pairs).
When we subscribe to this observable, we will recognize single-clicks and double-clicks from the original observable. See the following example code:
sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
pairObservable.Subscribe(it => {
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds:00000}ms| Pair received: {it}");        
});

EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_11");
SleepWithOutput(100);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_12");
SleepWithOutput(450);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_14");
SleepWithOutput(400);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_15");
SleepWithOutput(350);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_16");
SleepWithOutput(300);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_17");
SleepWithOutput(250);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_18");
SleepWithOutput(200);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_19");
SleepWithOutput(500);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_20");
SleepWithOutput(100);
EmitValue(clicksSource, "str_21");
SleepWithOutput(350);

This will generate the following output:
00017ms| Emit value str_11
00052ms| Sleep for 100ms
00152ms| Emit value str_12
00153ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=True
00153ms| Sleep for 450ms
00603ms| Emit value str_14
00603ms| Sleep for 400ms
00903ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=False
01003ms| Emit value str_15
01004ms| Sleep for 350ms
01303ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=False
01354ms| Emit value str_16
01354ms| Sleep for 300ms
01654ms| Emit value str_17
01654ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=True
01654ms| Sleep for 250ms
01904ms| Emit value str_18
01905ms| Sleep for 200ms
02105ms| Emit value str_19
02105ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=True
02105ms| Sleep for 500ms
02605ms| Emit value str_20
02605ms| Sleep for 100ms
02705ms| Emit value str_21
02705ms| Pair received: HasSecond=True, WasDoubleClick=True
02705ms| Sleep for 350ms

